# How to replace 0 into -1 in MATLAB output/result

Tags: matlab

I was working on the pn sequence. After I generated my pn sequence I need to verify an equation, but for that I need to change the zeros in my result to -1 and only then I can verify it.
Can someone please tell me how to replace/change 0 into -1 after getting the result. As there are 1023 bits in the result and I don't want to waste my time changing it manually one by one.

Here is my code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
x1=[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
n1=length(x1);
len1=2^n1-1;
p1(1,1) = x1(1,1);
z1 = x1;
for y1 = 2 : len1;
x1=z1;
for i = 1 : n1;
if (i==1)
z1(1,i) = xor  (x1(1,9),x1(1,10));
else
z1(1,i) = x1(1,i-1);
end
end
p1(1,y1)=z1(1,10);
end
subplot 211;
stem (p1);
p1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Just add this at the end of your script: `p1(p1==0) = -1;`

Comment: I did it. Also can you please tell me how to add all the output bits. As I need the sum of all the 1023 bits, but since I change 0 to -1 it is giving me this error: 'Attempted to access p1(0,1); index must be a positive integer or logical.'     I added this in my code to get the sum:  p1(p1==0) = -1;
k=0;
u1=0;
for k1 = 1:len1;
    k2 = p1(k,k1)+u1;
    u1=k2;
end

Comment: before inserting the line in the answer, type `sum(p1)`

Comment: Thank you,  It helped a lot              =)